# QGIS, hide header of layer group in print layout legend

Tags: qgis, print-composer, legend

Within the main QGIS window I group my layers in an attempt to have some sort of order within my project. When I come to create Layout and I want to add a legend I sometimes find that I want to remove the group name from the grouped layers within the legend.

This, however, leaves a 'gap' within the legend where the group name should be. Is there a way to 'collapse' that, so all the entries in the legend are evenly spaced?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the legend, go to `Item Properties > Legend Items` and uncheck the box `Auto update`. Then right-click on the Group you want to remove and check the box `Hidden`.

*Here, `group2` is hidden:*
[image]